# Accessing Raspberry Pi Webserver with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, raspberry-pi, webserver

I am looking for a way to connect a database to my WPF Application. I already connected it to a database which is installed on the same machine, but now I want my program to run on other computers as well, that means I need a server which I can access remotely. So I came across using a Raspberry Pi as WebService with an MySQL database and accessing this database with a Rest API. As I am quite new to these kind of problems (servers) I wanted to ask if anyone has experience with using a Raspberry Pi as Webserver and could give me some suggestions or tutorial recommendations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your goal is to have client applications access a database server on the network then you do not need to introduce a raspberry pi, and in fact that would be about the worst implementation I could think of. Choose your dbms (MySQL, MS SQL, whatever) and use it's documentation to get it set up for remote connecttions.

Comment: And if I want to connect to the database from an other network?

Comment: That is a networking issue that would still exist if you used a web server. I'm not a network admin but you would need routes between networks/subnets/whatever your topology is.

Comment: A raspberry isn't exactly super powered.  You realise you could use iis on that pc you have your wpf app on?  Or kestrel if you don't want iis on there. Have you considered cloud? If a raspberry will work then this must be pretty low throughput.

Comment: It is just for educational reasons so I don´t really care about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MYSQL instance running on a Raspberry Pi you don't need a WebService to connect to it. You need to set up the MySQL database and then you can connect via the appropriate connection string as long as you are on the same network as the Pi. I don't know what OR mapper you are using in your WPF application. But here is a guide to set up a MySQL database on a Pi and make it available on the network.

https://howtoraspberrypi.com/enable-mysql-remote-connection-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try as soon as my Raspberry arrives and maybe ask again if i get stuck at some point.